# Clean up a good question with possibly-conflicting comments and answers

Tags: discussion

The question *[What is the difference between statically typed and dynamically typed languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages)* has a highly-upvoted comment:

> Good question but your accepted answer is not the correct answer.

There seems to have been edits to both the question, the currently-accepted answer, and other answers since that time.

**Is the comment in question still correct in that the accepted answer is not correct?**

How can we improve the question, comments, and answers to relieve the confusion? I myself do not know that answer to the question asked.

Comment: Comment could become wrong after the edit. If you are expert then you should deal with confusion. I guess flagging wrong comment with many upvotes as "outdated" may be hard to deal for moderators who aren't experts, so simply write another comment (with ping to @comment_author) where you disagree and your comment will: 1) be seen by first comment poster and he will deal with it 2) get enough upvotes and then moderators will be able to remove first comment after someone's flag.

Comment: The comment is still correct, at least according to its author in [this comment on what they purport to be the "correct" answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages#comment29099950_1520342)

Comment: @Sinatr I'm not an expert, I found that question naturally because I, too, am looking for an answer.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: Two comments below that one, the same guy mentions that the 250+ word "factually incorrect" answer is incorrect in an extremely minor way that in no way invalidates the abundance of facts in that answer.

Comment: I didn't say the author's opinion was *valid*, I just said the comment is correct, according to that author :). It's also been upvoted a few times, so apparently it is a somewhat popular opinion. ‍♂️ I don't really care enough about the static/dynamic debate to care. Also, I tend to do my own research when I have these kinds of questions, and Stack Overflow is just one stop among many before I feel like I have anything close to a definitive answer.

Comment: Side note: the linked question is a good example why we try to avoid opinion-based questions... Since there is no formal definition of those terms everyone feel need to add they understanding...

Comment: Looks like the commentary was nuked